# Bundling data with your .spec file in PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

So I've read all of the questions here and cannot for the life of me see why this doesn't work. I have a .spec file that looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['newtestsphinx.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\speechfolder'],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=None,
         runtime_hooks=None,
         excludes=None,
         cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas + [('grammar2.jsgf', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\speechfolder\\grammar2.jsgf', 'DATA')],
      name='newtestsphinx.exe',
      debug=False,
      strip=None,
      upx=True,
      console=True )
```

so like all of the examples if I understand them, I added 'grammar2.jsgf' to the bundle in the root directory, I believe the format of this is ['path_to_put_in', 'path_its_in_now', 'label']

So then I run the command to create my new file:

pyinstaller --onefile newtestsphinx.spec

and the first thing I do now in my code is this:

```
print os.path.isfile('grammar2.jsgf')
```

it returns false 100%, and my program also can't find the file to use it. Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue at hand is that pyinstaller should extract a bunch of necessary supporting files to a temporary directory when it runs. When trying to access these supporting files, you need to pre-pend access to the files with the correct directory name.  From the [docs](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#adapting-to-being-frozen):

```
import sys
import os

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # we are running in a |PyInstaller| bundle
    basedir = sys._MEIPASS
else:
    # we are running in a normal Python environment
    basedir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

So then when trying to access your file:

```
print os.path.isfile(os.path.join(basedir, 'grammar2.jsgf'))
```

You should see it return True.  Another helpful thing to do is to print out the basedir, and ensure that execution doesn't end, using something simple like:

```
raw_input('Press enter to end execution.')
```

This will allow you to see where the temporary directory is - then you can go explore a little bit and get an idea of how it all works.